# Como abrir un modal cuando mando una variable en la misma pagina?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un problema que tengo una tabla cargada en una de sus columnas tengo el icono de modificar al tocar el icono mando una variable a la misma pagina y al mismo tiempo deseo abrir un modal el cual no estoy teniendo exito he probado de varias forma y no me da e igual he probado con que al cargar la pagina via php no me carga porque o da el modal sin enviarme la variable o no me da el modal ese es mi problema de igual forma copio el modal hecho de los ejemplos del AdminLTE.

```html
 <td style="text-align: center;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_modificar_pregunta">
                    <form action="../vistas/gestion_preguntas_vista.php?Pregunta=<?php echo $row['pregunta']; ?>">
                    <a href="../vistas/gestion_preguntas_vista.php?Pregunta=<?php echo $row['pregunta']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-xs far fa-edit" style="display:<?php echo $_SESSION['modificar_pregunta'] ?> ">
                    
                    </a>
</form>
                  </td>
                
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <form action="../vistas/gestion_preguntas_vista.php?Pregunta=<?php echo $row['pregunta']; ?>">
                    <a href="../vistas/gestion_preguntas_vista.php?Pregunta=<?php echo $row['pregunta']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-xs far fa-edit" style="display:<?php echo $_SESSION['modificar_pregunta'] ?> "  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_modificar_pregunta">
                    
                    </a>
</form>
                  </td>
                  
                                 
                      <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <form action="../vistas/gestion_preguntas_vista.php?Pregunta=<?php echo $row['pregunta']; ?>" ">

                    <a href="../vistas/gestion_preguntas_vista.php?Pregunta=<?php echo $row['pregunta']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-xs far fa-edit" style="display:<?php echo $_SESSION['modificar_pregunta'] ?> " >
                      <i class="far fa-edit" style="display:<?php echo $_SESSION['modificar_pregunta'] ?> " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_modificar_pregunta"  ></i>
                    </a>
</form>
                  </td>
```

```html
Este es el inicio del modal creado como decia no tengo.

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_modificar_pregunta">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Gestión de Preguntas</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>


               <!--Cuerpo del modal-->
            <div class="modal-body">
   




   <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Modificar pregunta</label>
             
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_pregunta_modificar" name="txt_pregunta_modificar" style="text-transform: uppercase" onkeypress="return Letras(event)" onkeyup="DobleEspacio(this, event)" required="" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['TxtPregunta'];?>">

                </div>

 <div class="form-group clearfix">
                      <div class="icheck-success d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxactivomodificar" name="checkboxactivomodificar" <?php echo $checkeado; ?> value="true">
                        <label for="checkboxactivomodificar">Activo
                        </label>
                      </div>
                </div>

          
<!--
              <p class="text-center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-raised btn-sm" id="" ><i class="zmdi zmdi-floppy"></i> Guardar</button>
              </p>
-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

            </div>




            <!--Footer del modal-->
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnmodificar_pregunta" name="btnmodificar_pregunta">Guardar Cambios</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div>

      <!-- /.  finaldel modal -->
```

Comment: tambien he probado esta opcion    

if (isset($_SESSION['TxtPregunta'])){

 ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modal_modificar_pregunta').modal('toggle')
});
</script>    

  <?php


  }

Comment: ¿El modal es personalizado o estás utilizando boostrap, materialize css u otro "framework" de estilos?

Comment: Es de boostrap bueno lo copie de la adminlte

Comment: Versión de boostrap?

Comment: acabo de copiar el modal para ver si me puedes ayudar de igual forma el adminlte que uso es AdminLTE-3.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo practico para que lo adaptes a tus necesidades.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Modal example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
  $autostart_modal = isset($_REQUEST['autostart_modal']) && $_REQUEST['autostart_modal']; 
  if($autostart_modal): 
?>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    })
  </script>;
<?php endif; ?>
```

En resumen si llega por el `request` la variable `autostart_modal` con un valor verdadero el modal comenzará desplegado.

La magia en realidad está a la hora de validar la variable, si es así agregamos una nueva etiqueta `script` a la pagina con el código que despliega el modal.

```
$('#exampleModal').modal('show');
```

Recuerda cargar la nueva etiqueta `script` al final de todas para asegurarte que funcione correctamente.

Comment: Esta forma funciono amigo muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda